# How do I solve this django-private-chat error?

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

so I've been trying to implement django-private-chat into an existing problem but always encountered an error. So, I tried to run the example project found on under django-private-chat on Github and I received the same error. Thanks for the help!

```
    25.04.20 10:45:49:ERROR:Error in connection handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/websockets/server.py", line 191, in handler
    await self.ws_handler(self, path)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_private_chat/handlers.py", line 259, in main_handler
    user_owner = get_user_from_session(session_id)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django_private_chat/utils.py", line 15, in get_user_from_session
    session = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 411, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1142, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/testEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 24, in inner
    raise SynchronousOnlyOperation(message)
django.core.exceptions.SynchronousOnlyOperation: You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.
25.04.20 10:45:49:DEBUG:server ! failing OPEN WebSocket connection with code 1011
25.04.20 10:45:49:DEBUG:server - state = CLOSING
25.04.20 10:45:49:DEBUG:server > Frame(fin=True, opcode=8, data=b'\x03\xf3', rsv1=False, rsv2=False, rsv3=False)
25.04.20 10:45:49:DEBUG:server x half-closing TCP connection
25.04.20 10:45:49:DEBUG:server - event = connection_lost(None)
25.04.20 10:45:49:DEBUG:server - state = CLOSED
25.04.20 10:45:49:DEBUG:server x code = 1006, reason = [no reason]
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Since I encountered this problem both with my own project and the example found on github here's the example link because it is the less complex project: [link to github](https://github.com/Bearle/django-private-chat/tree/dev/example)

Comment: this looks like a bug in `django_private_chat` possibly they do not fully support django3+ (that is what is raising this erro).

Comment: it's been 8days,have you been able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Django private CHAT isn't supported beyond Django 3.Try entering this in your settings.py file

```
os.environ["DJANGO_ALLOW_ASYNC_UNSAFE"] = "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Django Private Chat2](https://github.com/Bearle/django_private_chat2) supports upto django 4